# Which IDE to use for developing NodeJS application on Raspberry Pi?

Tags: node.js, ide, raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi3

I am pretty new to Node JS.I want to develop a Node JS application on my Raspberry Pi 3. This application will interact with sensors connected to the GPIO pins of Raspberry Pi. 
What IDE can i use on RPi  for coding and debugging?

Answer (score 2):

I am also new to NodeJS, but here is the setup I currently have:

1. I use Windows machine with Visual Studio 2015 Community Edition for writing and debugging code.
2. Installed Node.js Tools for Visual Studio: https://beta.visualstudio.com/vs/node-js/
3. On Raspberry PI installed Samba for sharing files with Windows machine:
   http://blogs.arcsoftwareconsultancy.com/pi/2013/03/07/windows-networking/
4. I keep the source code of the NodeJS app on the Raspberry in a Samba-shared folder.
5. I added RemoteDebug.js to the root folder of my app. You can locate the RemoteDebug.js on your machine by going to the following menu of Visual Studio 2015:
   Tools->Node.js Tools->Remote Debugging Proxy->Open COntaining Folder
6. For debugging, I launch the app on the Raspberry with the following command:

   > sudo node RemoteDebug.js server.js
7. Then I attach to the Node process running on the PI via Attach To Process dialog in VS (you need to pick Node.js remote debugging from the Transport dropdown):
   [image]